# clang: error: unknown argument: '-nvcc_options=ftz=true'

Tags: tensorflow, clang, nvcc

I am compiling tensorflow r1.2 with clang and cuda. But the following error shows up

`ERROR: /data/home/vimos/Public/git/github/ml/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:642:1: Couldn't build file tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/mirror_pad_op_gpu/tensorflow/core/kernels/mirror_pad_op_gpu.cu.pic.o: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:mirror_pad_op_gpu' failed: clang failed: error executing command /opt/llvm/bin/clang -mavx -mavx2 -mfma -msse4.2 -MD -MF bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/mirror_pad_op_gpu/tensorflow/core/kernels/mirror_pad_op_gpu.cu.pic.d ... (remaining 143 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
clang: error: unknown argument: '-nvcc_options=relaxed-constexpr'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-nvcc_options=ftz=true'`

I am using clang version

`➜  tensorflow git:(r1.2) ✗ /opt/llvm/bin/clang --version
clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/llvm/bin`

bazel version

`➜  tensorflow git:(r1.2) ✗ bazel version
Build label: 0.4.5
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Mar 16 12:19:38 2017 (1489666778)
Build timestamp: 1489666778
Build timestamp as int: 1489666778`

I am now trying compiling clang with trunk head. 
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I tried the newest version but in vein. I think clang does not support cuda well. I'd like to close the question for now.